# How to list all excel file names in specific foldder and total number of row used in each file using Excel VSTO C#

Tags: excel, vba, vsto, excel-addins

I am new to Excel add-in.

I have specific folder where I want Excel add-in to search for any excel file including sub folder and list down all file names and total number of row used in existing excel file where the add-in is running.

Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
Sub OpenAllExcelFiles()

Dim wb As Workbook, wbCSV As Workbook
Dim sPath As String, sFilename As String
Dim NbRows As Integer, rg As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

sPath = "C:\your_path\"       'Path of CSV Files
sFilename = Dir(sPath & "*.xlsx")


Do While Len(sFilename) > 0
    Set wbCSV = Workbooks.Open(sPath & sFilename)         'open file
    NbRows = wbCSV.Sheets(1).Range("A100").End(xlUp).Row  'nb of rows

    Set rg = wb.Sheets(1).Range("A100").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    rg = sFilename
    rg.Offset(0, 1) = NbRows


    wbCSV.Close False   'close file
    sFilename = Dir

Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Final result in my test case:

[image]